# How to initialize Facebook Pixel with data that will be populated after the initialization?

Tags: javascript, facebook, conversion-tracking

I have a one-pager campaign site which should collect `PageView` and `LEAD` event data for Facebook targeting with "advanced matching".

For `PageView`, I need to initialize the Pixel on page load. For advanced matching, I need to provide user data for initialization script — however, I only have user data available after user has submitted the data, which is when the `LEAD` event should be sent.

Is it possible to provide the initialization script with a "pointer" to a javascript variable that is used when sending the `LEAD` event? Help page hints at this, but all the examples have e.g. email parameter provided as plain text or sha256 hash; not as JS variable nor as a textual pointer to one.

From the ["Advanced Matching with the Pixel" help page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/pixel-with-ads/conversion-tracking#advanced_match):

> To enable this feature, modify the default FB pixel code to pass data
>   into the pixel init call.
>
> ```
> fbq('init', '<FB_PIXEL_ID>', { 
>     em: '{{_email_}}', 
>     // Data will be hashed automatically via a dedicated function in FB pixel
>     ph: '{{_phone_number_}}',
>     fn: '{{_first_name_}}'
>     ....
> })
> ```
>
> In the example above, you will need to replace email, phone_number,
>   first_name with the names of the variables on your website that
>   capture this data.

Let's say I have `user_email` variable in the same scope as `fbq-init`:

```
var user_email = '';
```

Later, after the form is submitted, this variable will be populated like

```
user_email = "john@example.com";
```

How should I reference the variable in `fbq`? (1) <del>Like this?</del>

```
fbq('init', 123456, { em: '{{_user_email_}}' });
```

(2) <del>Or like this?</del>

```
fbq('init', 123456, { em: 'user_email' });
```

(3) <del>Or should I provide it simply with the variable:</del>

```
fbq('init', 123456, { em: user_email }); // nb: user_email === false when this is run
```

(4) Or should I initialize the pixel without any matching data and later enrich it? (How?)

A reputable ad agency sent me with instructions to submit the name of the variable as in my example 2, but the help page hints at 1 without actually providing any real world examples.

---

I tried all the options 1–3, and it seems variables won't get re-evaluated in subsequent `fbq('track', …);` calls after the initialization. If `user_email` is blank to start with, none of the events will include hashed user data.

Moreover even if I start with a valid email `user_email = "john@example.com";` (also tried real domains instead of example.com) only method 3 will work — but, as expected, this is not dynamic, ie. if `user_email` changes the hashes won't.

It is as if there is no string-variable replacement to begin with.

Would the more proper question be: **how do I submit user data for advanced matching *after the pixel initialization*?** Instead of trying to make the initialization lazy/dynamic.

Comment: (2) requires actual values to be passed, not variable names. If you want the pixel code to read it from variables, then you need to use (1). Suggest you install the pixel helper Chrome extension, that helps with debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sadly, when I set `user_email = ''` and use `fbq('init', 1, { em: '{{_user_email_}}' });` to initialize pixel; send `PageView`; then set `user_email` to an actual email; then send `Lead`, I can see from both Pixel helper and Developer tools that *no* hashed user data is being sent with *neither* event (should be sent with `Lead`). If I set the email address manually when initializing the pixel (ie. `fbq('init', 1, {em: 'test@example.com'});` I can see the hashed email is sent with both events.

Comment: Not sure at what point it is supposed to grab the value of that variable. Try initializing `user_email` with an email address from the beginning, before you call the init method, to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @CBroe I tested that and included the results in the question. (Thanks again for the Pixel helper — sped up digging a lot)

Comment: I've been having trouble asking that same question. Thank you for summing it up here so clearly. Seems crazy that this isn't possible :-/

Comment: Searched everywhere and still no clear answer to this question which seems pretty important. In other words: can we init the pixel multiple times, every time we've got new data to improve the Advanced Matching? e.g. let's say it's inited without advanced matching, then later re-inited with `em`, and later with `ph` -- does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As a workaround* it is possible to generate a `Lead` event with email user data by loading the pixel (image) via javascript:

```
// here the user email is unknown, so PageView is generated without email
fbq('init', 123456, {});
fbq('track', 'PageView');

// Later the form is submitted via ajax, so the user email is known
$.ajax(…).done(function(data) {
    // I decided to sha256 hash the email address in the backend and return it for the javascript handler
    var pixel = document.createElement('img');
    pixel.src = 'https://www.facebook.com/tr/?id=123456&ev=Lead&ud[em]=' + data;
    document.body.appendChild(pixel);
    // confirmed by the Pixel helper Chrome extension, this does generate a valid tracking event
    // (ironically, we're loading the noscript version via javascript)
});
```

Of course, a pure `fbq` version would be more desirable. Also, I'm yet unaware of possible drawbacks, should there be any.

Answer (score 0):

> Or should I initialize the pixel without any matching data and later enrich it? (How?)

Not like if it is documented anywhere or is recommended by Facebook, but there's no reason apart from semantics to not being able to call `init` again at a later point in time with additional info.

So you can call `init` the normal default way first:

`fbq('init', 123456)`

And at a later point in time, when you have obtained additional user data, you can call `init` again basically enriching the already running `fbq` instance with additional data:

`fbq('init', 123456, { em: user_email } )` (`user_email` is a variable holding the address)

Only caveat is that you have to send an event after this additional `init` call, otherwise the provided data will not be sent to Facebook. But since your goal is to send a new event anyway this is okay.

So long story short:

**Feel free to call `fbq('init', ...)` multiple times, the following events will be enriched with the additional data.**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But how do you know it is okay to call fbq('init') multiple times?

Comment: I looked at the code and tested it and saw that it worked, because I saw the additional data being present in the subsequent network requests sending the events to FB servers. The only problem is since it is not documented nor recommended, future versions may break it. Although I don't think it would break since FB has no incentive preventing you from providing more data. If one thing they like, it is more data....